# C++ cmake errors BOOST_ROOT DOXYGEN

Tags: c++, boost, build, cmake, doxygen

I am trying to build a c++ implementation of hidden markov models - downloaded from

```
http://www.cs.au.dk/~asand/?page_id=152
```

I am compiling this on an ubuntu 12.04 with a g++ 4.6 compiler.

Following the instructions mentioned on the webpage, on typing

```
cmake .
```

I get the following errors,

```
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:101 (message):
The Boost C++ libraries was not found.  Get Boost from
http://www.boost.org/ or set the environment variable BOOST_ROOT to point
to the root of boost directory.
```

Could someone help me resolve these issues out.

My boost folder is situated at

```
/usr/local/boost_1_52_0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's telling you to set BOOST_ROOT environment variable. So just do it:

```
BOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/boost_1_52_0 cmake
```

(prefixing a command with setting of an environment variable in posix shell sets it for just that command; cmake will remember the value in CMakeCache.txt afterwards)

I suppose the fact it didn't find doxygen does not matter. You will should still be able to build the library, you just won't be able to generate nice documentation for it, but that probably exists on the web somewhere or you can read it in the headers directly anyway.